# Unexpected Token '.' on raspberry pi even though script runs fine on windows

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, raspberry-pi3

I am encountering an error when I go to start one of my Discord bots on my Raspberry Pi 3B.

```
/home/pi/Downloads/xx/xx/bot.js:301
  if (channel?.messages.cache.has(packet.d.message_id)) return;
              ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:915:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:963:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:60:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
```

When running the same bot on my main Windows 11 Machine, it runs perfectly fine.

NodeJS/NPM on both my main machine and my R-Pi are running v16.15.1. Is there any way I could fix this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: The `?.` syntax is fairly new. The JavaScript platform on your Raspberry Pi may need to be updated.

Comment: [Optional chaining is available starting Node 14](https://node.green/#ES2020-features-optional-chaining-operator-----), which suggests that the Raspberry Pi is running 13 or lower.

Comment: The error you cite should not appear when running this code using Node runtime versions >=14. Can you run `node -v` on your Raspberry Pi and confirm that the version is indeed v16.15.1?

Comment: @Pointy I just checked using `node -v` and it says its running v12.22.5 instead of what I thought. What's weird is it says that 12.22.5 is the latest version, even though its not.

I used `sudo apt-get install nodejs` to install it as well.

Comment: @M4X4 the apt repositories for whatever distro you use might not have the latest version of Node. That's quite common. You can add a more recent repository or download and install the version directly (there is a script for it - the easiest way to find it is saerrching for "install node X linux")

Comment: I use `https://deb.nodesource.com/node_18.x` in apt sources to get the latest node

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned on the [nodejs.org](https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#debian-and-ubuntu-based-linux-distributions) website, you can install the latest versions with the [NodeSource](https://github.com/nodesource/distributions#installation-instructions=) deb package:

```
curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_18.x | sudo -E bash -
# and then
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

The default packages on your system are not up-to-date.
Good day